# Problem to insert a colum from a list/array in Python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to insert a new column in my `dataframe` from a list.

but I'm getting an error and I've tried many different ways to solve it but didn't make any effect.

I'm getting an error at the last line

could you guys help me with that?

Follow the code bellow:

```
dataFrame = pd.read_html(html)

comprovantes = []
qtde_linhas = dataFrame[0].shape[0]

for comprovante_linha in range(0,qtde_linhas):
    comprovantes.insert(comprovante_linha, 'teste')

dataFrame["Comprovante"] = comprovantes
```

my actual error is:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
  File "C:\Users\MacInBox\Desktop\IS2B_PYTHON.py", line 57, in <module>
    dataFrame["Comprovante"] = comprovantes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `dataFrame` isn't a `pandas.DataFrame`, but a list of DataFrames.

See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html)

> Returns:
>
> dfs : list of DataFrames

Comment: thanks i saw your answer and i had a light!! HAHA, for example i use **dataFrame[0].insert(2,"Comprovante", comprovantes)** to solve my problem!! thanksss